# Random image on refresh?

Tags: javascript, random

i have a website which have random images each time the home page is loaded. But the problem of the random images is it still loaded when i click back to home page BUTTON again. Precisely i want the random images will display ONLY when i refresh the home page not the home page button,how would i do it?

Here is the following code:

```
JAVASCRIPT<Head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var y1 = 20;  
(document.getElementById) ? dom = true : dom = false;


var gallery = new Array();
gallery[0] = new      Array("earlywork001.jpg","earlywork002.jpg","earlywork003.jpg","earlywork004.jpg","earlywor k005.jpg");

function pickImageFrom(whichGallery)
{
var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * gallery[whichGallery].length);
document.write('<a href="images/earlywork/' + gallery[whichGallery][idx] + '"    class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )"><img src="images/earlywork/' +   gallery[whichGallery][idx] + '" width="402" height="180"></a>');
}

function hideIt() {
if (dom) {document.getElementById("popup").style.visibility='hidden';}
}

function showIt() {
if (dom) {document.getElementById("popup").style.visibility='visible';}
}

function placeIt() {
if (dom && !document.all) {document.getElementById("popup").style.top =    window.pageYOffset + (window.innerHeight - (window.innerHeight-y1)) + "px";}
if (document.all) {document.all["layer1"].style.top =   document.documentElement.scrollTop + (document.documentElement.clientHeight -   (document.documentElement.clientHeight-y1)) + "px";}
window.setTimeout("placeIt()", 10); }
</script>
</head>

HTML<Body>
<body onLoad="placeIt(); showIt()">
/*code*/
  <div id="content"><!--Start content-->
  <div id="popup" style="position:absolute; left:140px; width:410px; height:20px;  visibility:hidden">
   <div style="background-color:white; padding:3px; border:1px solid black">
   <span style="float:right; background-color:gray; color:white; font-weight:bold;   width='20px'; text-align:center; cursor:pointer" onclick="javascript:hideIt()">&nbsp;X&nbsp;</span>
   <script language="javascript">pickImageFrom(0);</script></div>
   </div>
   <img src="images/home.png" width="644" height="363" alt="home" class="content" />
   </div><!--End content-->
   </div><!--End body content-->
  /*code*/
```

Comment: Which 'home page button' do you mean? The browser home button or one on your page that we can't see?

Comment: i didn't include my home page button here

Answer (score 1):

I ran into some trouble searching for a similar solution sometime ago so I wrote this and I'm pasting it here in case somebody else comes to search this again.

```js
window.onload = choosePic;

var images = new Array("https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/2.jpg", "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/2.jpg", "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/52.jpg", "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/12.jpg", "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/7.jpg", "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/27.jpg", "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/13.jpg", "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/4.jpg", "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/52.jpg", "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/6.jpg", "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/23.jpg", "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/41.jpg", "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/28.jpg");

function choosePic(){
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    document.getElementById("random-image").src = images[randomNum];
}
```

```html
<img src="" alt="me" id="random-image">
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in an `if`:

```
if (document.URL == document.referrer) {
// your code here
}
```

The `document.referrer` will get you the url of the previous page. Match it to the current url in `document.URL`. If both do not match, then your page was navigated to from another page.